# How can I block google from crawling my page, but still let Baidu do it?

Tags: html, seo, baidu

I'd like to block only Google from crawling a specific page on my website, but I still want other search engines (Baidu first of all) to crawl it.

I have no idea if it's even possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a **robots.txt** file that blocks the userAgent of google

//in robots.txt

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Read more about robots.txt here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en